# Idiomatic way to to match against list of munch.munch objects?

Tags: python, openstack-shade

I am using the openstack shade library to manage our openstack stacks. One task is to list all stacks owned by a user (for example to then allow for deletion of them).

The shade library call `list_stacks()` returns a list of [munch.Munch](https://github.com/Infinidat/munch) objects, and basically I want to identify that stack object that has either an 'id' or 'name' matching some user provided input.

I came up with this code here:

```
def __find_stack(self, connection, stack_info):
        stacks = connection.list_stacks()
        for stack in stacks:
            if stack_info in stack.values():
                return stack
        return None
```

But it feels clumsy, and I am wondering if there is a more idiomatic way to solve this in python? (`stack_info` is a simple string, either the "name" or "id", in other words: it might match this or that entry within the "dict" values of the munched stack objects)

Comment: Given the additional info, I don't see anything wrong or clumsy with this approach, and I don't see why anyone would consider this not idiomatic. If `stack_info` was a dictionary you could have probably used some `set` operations but that would probably be an overkill. Anyway, your way is perfectly acceptable IMHO. You could consider making it *shorter* with `map` but that would hurt readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As my comment suggests, I don't *really* think there is something to improve.

However, performance-wise, you could use `filter` to push the loop down to C level which may be beneficial if there are a lot of `stacks`.

Readability-wise, I don't think that you would gain much.

```
def __find_stack(self, connection, stack_info):
    stacks = connection.list_stacks()
    return list(filter(lambda stack: stack_info in stack.values(), stacks))
```

However this approach is not "short-circuited". Your original code stops when it finds a match, and this one will not, so in theory you will get more than one match if they exist (or an empty list in case there is no match).

Comment: Really nice and thoughtful!